# Why when I checkout a new branch using Git and push this new branch to origin repo, the base commit ID is 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000?

Tags: git, phabricator

I'm using update hook in Git to check if this push has been approved in Phabricator(By connecting to mysql). When I trying to use the second param as old commitID in update script, I always get 40 `0`s like `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` when this reference(branch) was created by `git checkout -b master` and not pushed before.
But I want to get the last commitID of master to demonstrate the starting point of this reference.

like this:

last commitID of my master branch is `978881526a1be5dc49aeef93cd83679c2142eb60`
I'm using master branch to checkout a new branch like this `git checkout -b t1`
and then I code something and commit some times, so I got a new head of branch:`dfb3094b7e9f06a8bf49671b5bbab45dd5c4318e`
finally, I push this branch to origin using `git push origin t1`

I expected to get the params of update script as below:

```
$1 refs/xxx/t1

$2 978881526a1be5dc49aeef93cd83679c2142eb60

$3 dfb3094b7e9f06a8bf49671b5bbab45dd5c4318e
```

but I got them as below:

```
$1 refs/xxx/t1

$2 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

$3 dfb3094b7e9f06a8bf49671b5bbab45dd5c4318e
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no commit is in the repository, the old commit id is all zeros. This is the same for new branches, see also the explanations in [Git receive/update hooks and new branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511057) which recommends ways to get around this problem.